# Infinite quantum well width $L$ to $2L$ adiabatic process

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, potential, schroedinger-equation, adiabatic

If we change width of the infinite quantum well $L$ to $2L$ slowly enough, how it does change energy levels.

Answer (score 4):

After the process ends, the new energy levels will be just the normal energy levels of infinite quantum well with width 2L.

moreover,
by the [Adiabatic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem):

> A physical system remains in its instantaneous eigenstate if a given
> perturbation is acting on it slowly enough and if there is a gap
> between the eigenvalue and the rest of the Hamiltonian's spectrum

So if for example, you have a particle in the nth level it will stay in this level during the process and his energy will be the updated energy for nth level in the new well.